# Gravity Forms field entries into wp_query loop

Tags: functions, wp-query, filters, hooks, plugin-gravity-forms

I have a simple function that filters the page content when form (ID 18) is submitted. It simply displays the entry of field (ID 13)...

```
add_action("gform_after_submission_18", "set_post_content", 10, 2);
function set_post_content($entry, $form){

    //getting post
    $post = get_post($entry["post_id"]);

    //changing post content
    $post->post_content = $entry[13];

}
```

Instead of simply displaying the entry, I need to use it as a variable within a wp_query loop..

The result I need is a loop of titles from all posts of the post type selected by form field (ID 13). The form field (ID 13) will be radio buttons with options for various custom post types..

```
<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 
    'post_type' => '$martinsposttype',
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'posts_per_page' => '-1', 
    'order' => 'ASC'
) ); ?>

<ul>            
<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

<li><?php the_title(); ?></li>

<?php  endwhile; ?>
</ul>
```

How on earth do I tie this all up into my function so that the wp_query loop is performed upon submission and the $entry[13] is used for 'post_type' within that loop?

Answer (score 0):

On `gform_after_submission` save the gform entry in post meta.

```
update_post_meta( $entry["post_id"], '_gform_submission_18_entry_13', $entry[13] );
```

In your template:

```
new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_gform_submission_18_entry_13', true ) ) );
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't get my head around this.. In fact I had simplified my real requirements in the hope that I could figure it out from there..

Comment: I have managed to return what I want but it appears directly after <body>, not into the post div where I want it!?

Comment: Can't add the code I have into the comment as it's too long though.

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to use your suggestion Zlatev but I did make some progress.. I've posted it as a new question here:
http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/95891/gform-after-submission-content-not-appearing-in-post-div